# QT equivalent to JSplitPane

Tags: qt, user-interface, jsplitpane

I'l be short and sweet!

How can I put an object like JSplitPane in my gui QT application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QSplitter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qsplitter.html) ?